# Как сделать(проверки if)по индексам для удаления из списка и добавления.И было видно что дело добавилось в основной список и сохранилось

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Список команд: LIST открывает список, ADD добавляет что-то в список, DELETE удаляет что-то из списка");
        System.out.println("Вызовите команду : ");
//        var str = sc.next();
        ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>() {{
            add(0, "Почистить зубы");
            add(1, "Сделать зарядку");
            add(2, "Выпить стакан воды");
            add(3, "Приготовить завтрак");
            add(4, "Отправиться на работу");
        }};
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            switch (sc.next()) {
                case "LIST":
                    System.out.println("Ваш список дел: " + todoList);
                    continue;

                case "ADD":
                    System.out.println("Добавить дело в список: ");
                    todoList.add(sc.next());
                    System.out.println("Дело добавленно!" + " номер в списке: " + todoList.size());
                    continue;

                case "DELETE":
                    System.out.println("Удалить дело из списка: ");
                    todoList.remove(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Дело удалено! " + todoList.size());
                    continue;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Давайте выберем действие!");
                    break;
            }
        sc.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите проверять и когда. Сообщения после добавления и удаления вы выводите.

Comment: Сообщения выводятся в консоли, а мне нужно чтобы я видела их в списке постоянно. У меня все обнуляется с каждой итерацией.Проверка ввода пользователя(число или слово он ввел, а может вообще символы).

Comment: Вы на каждой итерации сканер закрываете. Вынесите из цикла sc.close(); ниже. и все заработает. Если я правильно понял вас

Comment: Спасибо. А как лучше сделать проверку? Например пользователь захотел добавить что-то в список по индексу, а потом просто строкой. Нет идей как это сделать внутри кейса Add через if.

Comment: Можно, а почему нет. Вам нужно только решить, что например если первый символ '#' то за ним идет индекс какого-то списка, иначе вы считаете, что это просто текст